# getLocation method in LookupService return null

Tags: java, geoip

```
LookupService lookup = new LookupService(url.getPath), LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);                               
Location locationServices = lookup.getLocation(ipAddress);
```

*ipAddress* is String , *lookup* is not null & *locationServices* is null

i used *geoip-api-1.2.10.jar* & *GeoLite database*

What I am missing?

Comment: Is this happening for all IP addresses? Which GeoLite database are you using?

Comment: i tried different ip addresses all are result in null

Comment: i have solved it, I changed the GeoLiteCity database i have used and then works fine. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information there what is lookupservice and where does it come from, is it one of your own classes or something you downloaded from the internet?